# Join трех таблиц

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Есть 3 таблицы:

```
class Movie < ApplicationRecord
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

class User < ApplicationRecord
has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy

class Vote < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :movie
end
```

Vote:

```
Vote id: nil, value: 0, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, user_id: nil, movie_id: nil
```

Нужно получить все Movie для User у которых Vote имеет определенное значение. Сделал это так:

```
def recommendation(level)
  h = { 'Recommended' => 1, 'Not recommended' => -1, 'Neutral' => 0 }
  if h[level]
    Movie.where(id: @current_user.votes.where(value: h[level]).pluck(:movie_id))
  else
    Movie.where.not(id: @current_user.votes.where(value: [-1, 0, 1]).pluck(:movie_id))
  end
end
```

Думаю, что тут нужно не таким образом это сделать, а соединением, но никак не получается составить запрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Movie.where(id: @current_user.votes.where(value: h[level]).pluck(:movie_id))
# WHERE movies.id IN (очень много чисел, загруженных ранее)
```

Уже это можно преобразовать в **один** запрос, просто заменив `pluck` (который безусловно и немедленно загружает данные) на `select`.

```
Movie.where(id: @current_user.votes.where(value: h[level]).select(:movie_id))
# WHERE movies.id IN (SELECT votes.movie_id FROM votes WHERE условия на голоса)
```

---

Соединением тоже можно. Я так понимаю, вы застряли на том, как в запросе на записи одной модели накладывать условия на записи другой. Это делается [методом `merge`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge):

```
relevant_votes = @current_user.votes.where(value: h[level])
# По сути это запрос к votes с двумя условиями:
# WHERE votes.user_id = <current_user_id> AND value = <h_level>

Movie.joins(:votes).merge(relevant_votes)
```

Использовать следует с осторожностью, поскольку соединения ко многим записям могут приводить к возврату одинаковых объектов по многу раз, за каждое совпадение по одному.

Здесь, я полагаю, уже есть ограничение на уникальность (unique constraint), не дающее одному пользователю оставить несколько голосов за один фильм, поэтому этого не произойдёт. Но вообще имейте это в виду. И, возможно, держите под рукой [метод `distinct`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct).